# Type inheritance

Tags: delphi, class, types

In a class unit I have the type

```
type
  TFolderType       = (
                      dirRoot,
                      dirDatabase,
                      dirDocs,
                      dirConfig,
                      dirBackup,
                      dirDown,
                      dirUp,
                      dirScripts,
                      dirLicense,
                      dirImages,
                      dirMail,
                      dirProjects,
                      dirInput,
                      dirOutput
                      );
```

Now I would like to inherit this class from another class and add some extra elements
Is that in any way possible or can I do this in another way
I have thought of creating a class with all the elements as properties but I am not sure if that is the way to go

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not class, rather it is an enumerated type. You cannot use inheritance with enumerated types. You will need to create a new enumerated type. Or perhaps solve the problem using something other than an enumerated type.

Comment: OK - I will change the whole thing to a class that will give me the inherit option

Answer (score 1):

Like [David](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20971200/757830) says, it is not a class.

As an alternative, you can declare your bigger enumeration like:

```
type
  TThingType = (dirThingA, dirRoot, dirDataBase, ..., dirOutput, dirThingY, dirThingZ);
```

And then declare your TFolderType as:

```
type
  TFolderType = dirRoot..dirOutput;
```

Some concerns:

- A *folder* 'needs' to be of type *thing*
- The prefix `dir` 'needs' to be meaningful for both *thing* and *folder*
- Current code that assumes enumeration index of the `TFolderType` elements needs to be rewritten, or add all 'new' elements in the back.